# Javascript to dynamically display JSON data based on two dropdown selections in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm tying to a implement pair of dropdown menus (student and subjects) which display students marks of a particular subject when selected. The displayed marks should dynamically change (without the need to click submit) when options of either dropdown menus are changed.

The marks data of students needs to be pulled from a json file.

The output marks need to be displayed in a  within the html.

JSON data

```
{
    "school": "Caldor School",
    "class": "Eleven",
    "student": {
        "sam": {"math": "75", "physics": "76", "chemistry": "37", "english": "76"},
        "chris": {"math": "30", "physics": "49", "chemistry": "31", "english": "45"},
        "ashley": {"math": "52", "physics": "98", "chemistry": "30", "english": "86"},
        "bert": {"math": "95", "physics": "63", "chemistry": "32", "english": "77"},
        "matt": {"math": "56", "physics": "34", "chemistry": "29", "english": "72"}
    }
}
```

HTML code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<select id="stud">
<option>Sam</option>
<option>Chris</option>
<option>Ashley</option>
<option>Bert</option>
<option>Matt</option>
</select>

<select id="subject">
<option>Math</option>
<option>Physics</option>
<option>Chemistry</option>
<option>English</option>
</select>

<div id="marks"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone kindly point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: get all keys of subject & math using Object.key property. ie.
var students = Object.keys(cl["student"]);
& var subjects = Object.keys(cl["student"][students[0]]);

Answer (score 0):

The selection box has an `onchange` event that occurs when the value of an element has been changed.
You can try something like the example below to get the student id and the subject.
The next step will be to parse the JSON data for the student and then for the subject.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>

<p>When you select a new car, a function is triggered which outputs the value of the selected car.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>



</body>
</html>
```